# Scout Eclipse ScoutServerTestRunner on client tests

Tags: junit, client-server, server, eclipse-scout

now I run on new problems with scout testing.

I have Client fragment project for testing and I would like to test some templates I created.

My problem is that this templates contains some SmartFields and I would like to test them. For this I probably need `ScoutServerTestRunner`, so the server is up and running.

But If I try to add it I get error :

```
@RunWith(ScoutServerTestRunner.class)
@ServerTest()
```

I get error :

```
ServerTest cannot be resolved to a type
```

, all of my `assert` imports are deleted and I get error on my `package` line suggesting me `Configure build path`.

My guess is that this can't be done because it is client fragment and it can't connect to server. 
But how then test smartFields ?

Comment: If I run with only ScoutClientTestRunner I get :  serverURL is null. Check proxyHandler extension. Example value is: http://localhost:8080/myapp/process

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From your question I guess that there is some misunderstanding...

---

`ScoutServerTestRunner` and `@ServerTest` is something similar to `ClientServerTestRunner` and `@ClientTest` but for the server. You will need it for tests testing the server.

The classes are located in the `org.eclipse.scout.rt.testing.server` bundle.

---

If in a client test you need a server you have two possibilities:

### A/ Start a server

You can start a server

[image: Scout tests with a server]

This will probably not be the normal server (the one like in production) because you want to control the database or some external services. Authentication might also be slightly different (in order to control it and to have something compatible with your tests)

For the integration in your maven build, the maven-cargo plugin can be used to start your server before executing the client test suite.

### B/ Mock the server services

Each of the services call that creates a ProxyService calling the server, can be replaced by mock (client only).

[image: Scout tests with mocked server services]]

This is the preferred way for unit test, because you do not rely on a deployed server. You can also define for each test what the server answer will be.
This solutions requires probably initially more work, but in my opinion it worth it.

To register an alternative service, you can use:

```
TestingUtility.registerServices(
     <activator instance>, 
     <priority>, 
     <service instances>
);
```

The service with the higher priority will win.

In each test, do not forget to un-register the alternative services you have registered.

---

SmartFields are using CodeTypes or LookupCalls. In case of a `LookupCall`, the `LookupCall` is probably calling the server through a `LookupService`. In case of a `CodeType`, the `SmartField` is internally using the `CodeLookupCall` class relying on a `ICodeService`.

In both cases, if you want to run your test without a server, you need to ensure that the client uses alternative implementations of the required services that do requires a server.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. For option (1), I assume that is not enough if I just "normally" start scout server (scout-server.dev.product -> run). Can you maybe provide some details how to do it?

Comment: Well you also need to configure where your server is. I guess your `ClientSession` has a line to do it: `setServiceTunnel(new ClientHttpServiceTunnel(this, UriUtility.toUrl(getBundle().getBundleContext().getProperty("server.url"))));` in `execLoadSession()`. This means that the `server.url` property is read. We usually defined it in the `config.ini` file. When you run your test, you can indicate that you want to use a specific `config.ini` file. Check the "Configuration" Tab of your "Run configuration". An other approach is to create a TestingClientSession where the url is hard coded.

Comment: I have trouble with this : As you say I set config.ini in run config to : scout.ui.rap/products/development/config.ini and I get error : ERROR: Duplicate alias. Failed to register servlet for [alias="/", contributor="com.sixt.leasing.core.scout.server[22]"] and non tests are run. If I set config.ini to scout.ui.rap/products/production/config.ini I get  ProcessingException[ProcessingStatus[ERROR code=0 Calling ... Caused by: org.eclipse.scout.rt.shared.servicetunnel.HttpException: 404 - NOT_FOUND for all services, but all tests except those witch need services are performed.

Comment: You need to check which servlet is a duplicate alias. Without seeing your code, I can not help...When you set it to the second `config.ini`, what is the value of `server.url` in this file? Are you sure that your server is reachable at this url? Maybe you need a special `config.ini` for the tests. As I wrote in my answer, I am not really a fan of integration test (test with a server) I prefer unit test with mocked server services.